# R loop named data frames in list

Tags: r

I have two data frames containing data

```
seed(1234)
dfX <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 25), 20, 5), row.names = paste("AB", sample(1:20, replace=FALSE), sep=""))
colnames(dfX) <- c("G", "H", "I", "J", "K")
dfY <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 25), 20, 5), row.names = paste("AB", sample(1:20, replace=FALSE), sep=""))
colnames(dfY) <- c("G", "H", "I", "J", "K")
```

I also have the names of the data frames in

```
asNames <- c("Test1", "Test2")
```

Now I want to create a list LL containing these two data frames, but on such a way that I can use LL$Test1 to give me data frame dfX. Of course I can use

```
list("Test1" = dfX, "Test2" = dfY)
```

But this is not dynamic, as I have a variable number of data frames. I had hoped something like this would work

```
list(asNames[1] = dfX, asNames[2] = dfY)'
```

But this gives error message

> Error: unexpected '=' in "list(asNames[1] ="

Also `list(dfX, dfY)` does not give me the required result, as names(LL) = NULL, and I can only retreive dfX by LL[[1]].

That is the basic part of the question. Another dimension is when I have a whole lot of data frames with their names stored in vNames. How can I add the data frames into list LL2, and use the names in vNames.

I guess it is something like

```
LL2 <- lapply(seq_along(vNames), function(x, LL, vN){c(LL, vN[x] = get(vN[x])}, LL = LL2, vN = vNames)
```

Many  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LL <- setNames(list(dfX, dfY), asNames)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: That is nice, and fixes the first time I do this. But now I have data frame dfZ which I want to include in LL. How do I do this?

Comment: @JaapPaap `append(LL, dfZ)`

Comment: But this does not give it the name I want.